# Restrict button use on count limit

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, webforms

I want to make a button and then restrict it on the number of clicks 
So far i have not succeeded but this is how far i came.
This is my button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnClearSesson" runat="server" Text="Reset"  onclick="btnClearSesson_Click" />
```

This is what i am doing

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim lUserName As String
Static count As Integer

count = count + 1

lUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

If count < 10 && lUserName = "ADMIN" Then

  btnClearSesson.Visible = True

  Else

  btnClearSesson.Visible = False

End If

End Sub
```

So my problem is that the count starts again again and not get incremented

The button when clicked must increase count and then if count is greater than 10 it will stop showing the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared the static variable inside page load so it will get flushed every time the page load

so declare it with global scope 
 like this

```
Static count As Integer
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

Dim lUserName As String


count = count + 1

lUserName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

If count < 10 && lUserName = "ADMIN" Then

  btnClearSesson.Visible = True

  Else

  btnClearSesson.Visible = False

End If

End Sub
```

and one more thing you should increase the count in button click event handler not in page load.

hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes my bad it should not be in page load

Comment: I had tried your suggestion but now the problem is with every load it becomes visible again even if i have crossed the limit that i had put on

How can the clicks be counted and then used to put limit on clicks

Comment: add your new code to the question and tell me where do you put your button hide code

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your code in the Page Load event and no in the click event

Try the following code:

```
Static count As Integer

Protected Sub btnClearSesson_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 

   Dim lUserName As String = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name
   count +=1
   btnClearSesson.Visible = count < 10 && lUserName = "ADMIN"

End Sub
```

In the page load, if the user does not click the button, but refresh the page, count will be incremented anyway.